# How to add JPanels one after another to a scrollbar (or some other swing container)

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I created the code below so that I could dynamically add panels, vertically, one after another, to a scrollpane.

Each panel is supposed to have something drawn on it (a graph based on data points loaded from a file, though I changed the code to make it look like what it is painting is a string for simplicity's sake).

```
public void btnShow(Main aThis, ActionEvent evt) {
    String cont = drv.load(fln.filePoints, true);//load file content
    String d[] = cont.split(utf.splt[1]);//split using special symbol
    for (int i = 1; i <= d.length - 1; i++) {
        String fn = d[i] + pth.endPoints;//data split is a filename
        String s = drv.load(fn, true);//load file content
        // Paint string onto panel
        class MyPanel extends JPanel {
            public MyPanel() {
                setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
            }
            DriveRouter drv = new DriveRouter();

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(100, 100);
            }

            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawString(s, x, y);
            }
        }
        //
        JPanel pan = new MyPanel();
        //Add panel to scrollpane
        aThis.jScrollPane1.add(pan);
    }
}
```

The problem is, nothing is showing up.

How am I supposed to go about adding these panels vertically, one after another, to my container (I chose a jScrollPane for this case).

Ideally, the end product should just look like a scrollable list of text (since each panel has a string painted on). Of course, with my actual code this will instead be a scrollable list of plotted graphs, each graph being an individual JPanel.

Please, help!

Note: I tried replacing the scrollpane with a jTabbedPane, and the first once was painted, and there were tabs created for every single pane. Unfortunately, for whatever reason, when I switched tabs nothing showed up.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be adding things to the JScrollPane itself but rather to its viewport -- check the [JScrollPane tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) which will explain why this is so.

Also, if you're adding things dynamically, you need to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` after adding or removing on the container so that the components added are laid out and are repainted.

Also if you're adding multiple JPanels to the JScrollPane, then you should add a "master" JPanel to the viewport first, give it a decent layout manager, and then dynamically add the new JPanels to this JPanel, again revalidating and repainting.

If you need more comprehensive answer, create and post your [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks, it was a success! I added :jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jPanel2);
jPanel2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jPanel2, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)); And then did revalidate() and repaint() to pan for each time I added to jPanel2 (JPanel pan = new MyPanel();
            aThis.jPanel2.add(pan);
            pan.revalidate();
            pan.repaint();)